# How to understand the Evaluation order of Classes in MDN?

Tags: javascript, class

[Evaluation order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#evaluation_order)

I didn't understand the content about Evaluation order. There are many points that I'm confused about, and I hope someone can help clarify them for me.

1. "The extends clause, if present, is first evaluated. It must evaluate to a valid constructor function or null, or a TypeError is thrown."

```js
class bar extends null {} // TypeError: Super constructor null of bar is not a constructor
```

why? According to the description above, this should be correct.

2. "For each instance field (public or private), its initializer expression is saved. The initializer is evaluated during instance creation, at the start of the constructor (for base classes) or immediately before the super() call returns (for derived classes)."

```js
class F {
  x = 1; // 2
  constructor() {
    this.y = 10; // 3
  }
}
class P extends F {
  j = 2; // 4
  constructor() {
    super(); // 1
    this.k = 20; // 5
  }
}
let p = new P();
```

why? I executed this code, and the result is completely different from what it describes.

Comment: What is your expected order in the second point?

Comment: How can you tell the order of evaluation in #2? The expressions have no side effects, and you don't try to access any of the fields.

Comment: I get no error for the first example in Chrome.

Comment: The order of the second point is the execution order I observed while debugging.

Comment: I'm sorry, the first example throws an error when instantiated

Comment: But the question is about order of evaluation of the `extends` clause, not about `new bar`

Comment: Oh, thank you. Regarding the first question, I might have misunderstood.

Comment: You shouldn't ask two different questions at once. Someone will answer #1, someone else answers #2, which one will you accept? Please split this into separate questions so each can be answered.

Comment: Since #1 has been answered, I suggest you accept that answer and post a new question for #2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why `class bar extends null {}` throws an error?

In [Extending null](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends#extending_null) secion you can read that:

> extends null was designed to allow easy creation of objects that do not inherit from Object.prototype. However, due to unsettled decisions about whether super() should be called within the constructor, it's not possible to construct such a class in practice using any constructor implementation that doesn't return an object.

And then there is code that actually works:

```
class NullClass extends null {
  constructor() {
    // Using new.target allows derived classes to
    // have the correct prototype chain
    return Object.create(new.target.prototype);
  }
}

const proto = Object.getPrototypeOf;
console.log(proto(proto(new NullClass()))); // null
```